# Youtube API Errors in console for 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'. and net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

My auth.js is getting two error when running on http://localhost

```
Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=161882282037-ol1lu4rp1q9qs17qsfjub0q2fil7au9a.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube&immediate=true&include_granted_scopes=true&proxy=oauth2relay345555543&redirect_uri=postmessage&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&response_type=token&gsiwebsdk=1&state=796381777%7C0.998470879&authuser=0&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.2sYoz5cQVqo.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCNCqOBGqlGE0dE8R-n44r2KGTwetA' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
cb=gapi.loaded_0:545 GET https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=161882282037-ol1lu4rp1q9qs17qsfjub0q2fil7au9a.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube&immediate=true&include_granted_scopes=true&proxy=oauth2relay345555543&redirect_uri=postmessage&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&response_type=token&gsiwebsdk=1&state=796381777%7C0.998470879&authuser=0&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.2sYoz5cQVqo.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCNCqOBGqlGE0dE8R-n44r2KGTwetA net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE
```

here is my code for auth.js:

```
// The client ID is obtained from the {{ Google Cloud Console }}
// at {{ https://cloud.google.com/console }}.
// If you run this code from a server other than http://localhost,
// you need to register your own client ID.
var OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = '161882282037-ol1lu4rp1q9qs17qsfjub0q2fil7au9a.apps.googleusercontent.com';
var OAUTH2_SCOPES = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'
];

// Upon loading, the Google APIs JS client automatically invokes this callback.
googleApiClientReady = function() {
  gapi.auth.init(function() {
    window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
  });
}

// Attempt the immediate OAuth 2.0 client flow as soon as the page loads.
// If the currently logged-in Google Account has previously authorized
// the client specified as the OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID, then the authorization
// succeeds with no user intervention. Otherwise, it fails and the
// user interface that prompts for authorization needs to display.
function checkAuth() {
  gapi.auth.authorize({
    client_id: OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
    scope: OAUTH2_SCOPES,
    immediate: true
  }, handleAuthResult);
}

// Handle the result of a gapi.auth.authorize() call.
function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
  if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
    // Authorization was successful. Hide authorization prompts and show
    // content that should be visible after authorization succeeds.
    $('.pre-auth').hide();
    $('.post-auth').show();
    loadAPIClientInterfaces();
  } else {
    // Make the #login-link clickable. Attempt a non-immediate OAuth 2.0
    // client flow. The current function is called when that flow completes.
    $('#login-link').click(function() {
      gapi.auth.authorize({
        client_id: OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
        scope: OAUTH2_SCOPES,
        immediate: false
        }, handleAuthResult);
    });
  }
}

// Load the client interfaces for the YouTube Analytics and Data APIs, which
// are required to use the Google APIs JS client. More info is available at
// https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/dev/dev_jscript#loading-the-client-library-and-the-api
function loadAPIClientInterfaces() {
  gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
    handleAPILoaded();
  });
}
```

This is really my first attempt at using the youtube api so i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here?

My api and client id in the developers console look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`X-Frame-Options` is a HTTP header sent by the server (`accounts.google.com`). When a browser is told by a webpage (e.g. `http://localhost`) to display another page (e.g. `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/...`) inside the "host" page via an iFrame, it will first check if the embedded page sends this header. If it is set to `sameorigin`, **the browser will refuse** to render the iFrame. `sameorigin` means that this page should only be accessed directly or embedded into a page with the same origin (=same domain).

This is a security mechanism. The server tells the browser: "Please don't embed me into other webpages, this might be a security risk for the user." Of course the browser doesn't have to obey this request, but I'd go so far as to say that all major browsers do - since they were designed to keep their users safe. If someone was to design his/her own web-browser, he/she could of course choose to ignore the header and render the iFrame regardless.

What this means for you is that you have to redirect your users to the authorization page (`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/...`) instead of embedding it. Now since you use the client library and the official example along with it, the question is why this doesn't work. My best guess is that Google has changed their OAuth policy to block cross-origin embeds but hasn't updated their library documentation to account for that change. The only viable option I see, since I'm not familiar with the JavaScript client library, is to do the authorization manually, without the library, and then use the library for the actual YouTube API requests.